# Нужно получать данные из таблицы MsSQL, и по данным создать таймер

Tags: c#

```js
        cn.Open();

               using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select s.id, s.name_ru, s.sendType, c1.cod, s.typPeriod, c2.name_ru, s.metaAlg, m.cod, s.dt_send, s.dt_beg, s.dt_send_daytime, s.dt_period_end from FROM Shedule s  inner join ClBaseItem c1 on s.sendType=c1.id inner join ClBaseItem c2 on s.typPeriod=c2.idinner join MetaAlg m on s.metaAlg=m.id", cn))

    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
      adapter.Fill(dt);
     

      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
          string dt_str = row["s.dt_send_daytime"].ToString();

          string[] dt_str_tmp = dt_str.Split(':');

          switch (row["c2.name_ru"].ToString())
          {
              case "Час":
                  Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[2]);//мм
                  break;

              case "Неделя":
                  Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[0] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[1]);//дд:чч
                  break;

              case "День":
                  Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[1] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[2]);//чч:мм
                  break;

                  case "5 минут":
                  Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[3]);//сс
                  break;

              case "10 минут":
                  Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[3]);//сс
                  break;

              case "30 минут":
                  Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[2] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[3]);//мм:сс
                  break;

          }
          
            MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();
            myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(row["s.dt_send_daytime"]);
            myTimer.datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(row["s.dt_beg"]);
            myTimer.id = Convert.ToInt32(row["s.id"]);
            myTimer.alg = Convert.ToString(row["m.cod"]);
            myTimer.Dt_Begin = Convert.ToDateTime(row["s.dt_beg"]);
            myTimer.Dt_Period_End = Convert.ToDateTime(row["s.dt_period_end"]);
            myTimer.st = row["st"].ToString();
            myTimer.comment = row["comment"].ToString();
            myTimer.dt_create = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dt_create"]);
            myTimer.dt_update = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dt_update"]);
           
            
  
           
            myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
            myTimer.AutoReset = true;
            myTimer.Enabled = true;                  
      }

          
           }
                     cn.Close();
             
            }
           Console.WriteLine("Идёт запись...");
           Console.WriteLine("Нажмите ENTER чтобы выйти");
           Console.Read();
}


            static void OnTimeout(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {

                var id = new [] {((MyTimer)sender).id};
                var alg = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).alg};
                var date = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).datetime };
                var st = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).st.ToString() };
                var comment = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).comment.ToString() };
                var beg = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).Dt_Begin };
                var end = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).Dt_Period_End };
                var cr = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).dt_create };
                var upd = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).dt_update };
               
                string sql = string.Format("Insert Into Alg_stack" +
                   "(id,metaAlg,datetime, st, comment, dt_beg, dt_end, dt_create, dt_update) Values(@id, @alg, @date, @st, @comment, @begin, @end, @create, @update)");

                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.1.156;Initial Catalog=ihd_aktobe;User ID=sa;Password=mypass";

                    cn.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
                    {

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alg", alg);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", st);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", comment);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@begin", beg);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@create", cr);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@update", upd);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    cn.Close();
```

Comment: Ну и создавайте в цикле while (dr.Read()) в чем проблемма

Comment: вот так получилось

Comment: можно и с адаптером с дататаблом =)

Comment: теперь, мне надо создать интервал таймера по таблице, как я сделал с параметрам

Comment: я попробовал  так =>  MyTimers.Last().Interval = dt.Rows[1]["timer_int"]; но выдает ошибку

Comment: я обновил ответ

Comment: Это что за покемон? row["2017-11-12"] у Вас колонка в базе "2017-11-12" называется???

Comment: Просто написал так) Эту колонку нужно создать  в другом таблице

Comment: В принципе код правильный?

Comment: Ну во первых создайте представление в БД, чтобы оно возвращало список тех колонок, которые Вы используете в таймере, как это делать смотрите гугль и язык запросов SQL. А в коде просто берёте эти колонки и пихаете в параметры таймера, и не важно сколько этих параметров будет 1 или 1000. Код я обновил ниже

Comment: я код обновил выше. Ещё ошибка выходит. Ругается что `Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "FROM"`

Comment: From 2 раза. Внимательнее с синтаксисом

Comment: Что не так => Ошибка: Столбец "s.dt_send_daytime" не принадлежит таблице

Comment: Возможно столбец [dt_send_daytime] не принадлежит таблице [Shedule]. А вообще это не относится к вопросу.

Comment: я проверил, s.dt_send_daytime столбец принадлежит таблице `shedule`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39879/discussion-between---and-propro17).

Comment: вы не отвечаете(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
public class MyTimer : System.Timers.Timer
{
  public string alg{ get; set; }
  public DateTime Dt_Begin { get; set; }
  public DateTime Dt_Period_End { get; set; }
  public int id { get; set; }
  public DateTime datetime { get; set; }
  public string st { get; set; }
  public string comment { get; set; }
  public DateTime dt_create { get; set; }
  public DateTime dt_update { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
  {
    cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=ПРИМЕР-ПК;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True";
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table_Timer", cn))
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
      adapter.Fill(dt);
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
            MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer()
            myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(row["Interval"]);
            myTimer.alg = row["alg"].ToString();
            myTimer.Dt_Begin = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Dt_Begin"]);
            myTimer.Dt_Period_End = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Dt_Period_End"]);
            myTimer.id = Convert.ToInt32(row["id"]);
            myTimer.datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(row["datetime"]);
            myTimer.st = row["st"].ToString();
            myTimer.comment = row["comment"].ToString();
            myTimer.dt_create = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dt_create"]);
            myTimer.dt_update = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dt_update"]);
            myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
            myTimer.AutoReset = true;
            myTimer.Enabled = true;                  
      }
    }
    cn.Close();
  }
}


static void OnTimeout(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  //Тут код таймера
}
```

Лист в Вашем случае я не вижу надобности создавать...

Comment: Спасибо! Если что буду спрашивать)

Comment: myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
  myTimer.AutoReset = true;
  myTimer.Enabled = true;  это у меня отдельно стоит

Comment: можно да внутрь впихнуть

Comment: Почему бы и нет. Зачем три цикла создавать? А для типов, наследуемых от [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) лучше использовать [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: у меня три таймера, можете пример)

Comment: Количество таймеров будет зависеть от количества строк в DataTable

Comment: а можно с несколькими таймерами???

Comment: не понимаю вопроса, я же Вам ответил "Количество таймеров будет зависеть от количества строк в DataTable"

Comment: ой извините, я хотел сказать с несколькими *параметрами*

Comment: Для начала код класса "MyTimer" в студию

Comment: то есть один таймер с несколькими ` myTimer.Parameter = row["timer_param"];`